# Selenium override FindsBy attribute in derived class

Tags: c#, selenium, attributes, overriding

I use Page Object Model pattern with PageFactory to initialize `IWebElement` properties/fields. My problem is that I want to have derived class which have overrided IWebElement with diffrent [FindsBy] attribute. My base class:

```
public class ConfigurationMenuPage : PageInfo, IConfigurationMenuPage
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_contents_ctl27")]
    protected virtual IWebElement _campaignsConfigLink { get; set; }
```

And my derived class:

```
 public class ConfigurationMenuPage21 : ConfigurationMenuPage
 {
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "otherId")]
    protected sealed override IWebElement _campaignsConfigLink { get; set; }
```

The problem is that `_campaignsConfigLink` property initializes with base attribute (with id "ctl00_contents_ctl27), instead overrided one (with id otherId). How can I force overrided property to initialize with its FindsBy attribute?

Regards,

Cybul26

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the declaration in `ConfigurationMenuPage` and let the derived class declare it? One workaround would be to use a CSS selector with an OR operator, `#ctl00_contents_ctl27, #otherId`.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I decided to `ConfigurationMenuPage` be an abstract class with abstract properties and let derivered classes to declare its properties.